# Issue in handling pipe delimited flat files,each field within double quotes. What can be a solution here

Tags: unix, awk, ksh, gawk

I have to handle pipe delimited flat files, in which each field comes within double quotes.

sample data:

```
"1193919"|"false"|""|"Mr. Andrew Christopher Alman"|""|""|"Mr."
```

I have written many gawk commands in my scripts. Now the issue is:

issue:
Consider this row: `"1193919|false||Mr. Andrew Christopher Alman"|""|"Mr."`
My script is taking the above as 6 different fields

```
"1193919
false
[null]
Mr. Andrew Christopher Alman"
[null]
"Mr."
```

But the data files are sent with the intent that 
`"1193919|false||Mr. Andrew Christopher Alman"` should be taken as one field, as surrounded by double quotes.

My thought: I was thinking to change the field separator `from | to "|"`
This has few issues. The last and first fields will come as `"1193919` and `Mr."`
i dont want to use '`["][|]["]|^["]|["]$'` as field separator, because this will increase the number fields and my other codes will have to go though a major change.

I am asking for a solution something like:
Use | as a field separator only if it is followed by " and preceded by ". But the field separator will be | and not "|"

issue 2:

```
"1193919""|"false"""|""|"Mr. Andrew Christopher Alman"
```

At the same time I want to report an error for `"false"""`, something like `/^"["]+ | ["]+["]$/ and not /^""$/`
Good data should be in below format

```
"1193919"|"false"|""|"Mr. Andrew Christopher Alman"
```

Comment: good solutions below, but why send data with field delimters embedded in fields. Use a value for FS that isn't in the data would be another solution to this problem. Good luck.

Comment: Sometimes you just have data in that way, a data field may just have a delimiter as a data, and you just gotta handle it. I'm writing this scripts for handling huge amount of data(for a data warehouse). And I expect all sorts of data.

Any thoughts on issue 2 solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `gawk`'s `FPAT` variable to define quoted fields

```
$ gawk -v FPAT='[^|]*|"[^"]*"' '{print $1}'
```

and add your logic around the number of field etc.

Comment: Thank you. But how can I overcome issue 2, as I have mentioned in the question? What is the actual syntax to convey the below Pseudocode.                    /^"["]+ | ["]+["]$/ and not /^""$/

Comment: Could you please explain your solution? What I understand is, the data field can not be "|", or it can not be " within double quotes. But I want to write the data field can also be "|" if within double quotes. I want "|" should not be considered as a special character(field separator) when inside double quotes

Comment: Now I understand the solution. But I dont have FPAT option with gawk in my system. ANy alternative?

Answer (score 1):

The main idea is to handle all irregularities before `awk` (because many irregular cases are possible and `awk` works best on regular files).

You can replace specific patterns with a unique symbol that doesn't occur within fields and then use it as a field delimiter:

```
sed 's/"|"/"\t"/g' file.txt |\
awk -F '\t' '{for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++){print i, $i} }'
```

I'd use something that is highly unlikely to occur in a text, e.g. vertical tab `\v`. If you are not sure about contents of the fields, then you can determine a symbol that is not present in the current chunk of data and process it with this symbol as a delimiter.

The same approach works for issue 2. If you know that some patterns are incorrect, then you can either exclude or fix them before processing, e.g. with

```
sed 's/\([^|"]\)"\+|/\1"|/g'
```

Comment: Thanks Andrey. But I'm writing to handle huge amount of data for a data warehouse, and I have no idea, what wont be there in the data field. And any thoughts for the issue 2 as I've mentioned in the question.. Thank you

Comment: Thank you Andrey. Do you have any idea, what are other characters that are very unlikely to occur in a text?

Comment: It depends on the data. If your environment supports Unicode, you can play with non-characters, e.g. try `echo -e 'a\uffffb' | awk -F "$(echo -e "\uffff")" '{for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++){print i, $i} }'`.